# If $31|6x+11y$ then $31|x+7y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

If $31|6x+11y$ then $31|x+7y$. The only way I can think of to solve this problem is to use linear algebra and show that these two are depended.

$\det \begin{pmatrix}6&1\\ 11&7\end{pmatrix}=31 \equiv 0_{31}$

What are other ways to tackle this?

Answer (score 4):

$\begin{align}
         & 31 \mid 6x+11y \\ 
\implies & 31 \mid 6x+42y \\
\implies & 31 \mid 6(x+7y) \\
\implies & 31 \mid x+7y    \\
\end{align}$

Comment: I like this solution.

Answer (score 4):

Since $6$ and $31$ are coprime and $11 \equiv 6 \cdot 7 \mod 31$, $6 x + 11 \equiv 6 (x + 7) \equiv 0 \mod 31$ if and only if $x + 7 \equiv 0 \mod 31$.

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: @DHMO: This answer was posted precisely 87 seconds after yours. It is safe to assume that it was started before yours was posted.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to eliminate one of the variables  $$6x+11y-6(x+7y)=31y$$

$$\implies6x+11y\equiv6(x+7y)\pmod{31}$$

$$\implies31|(6x+11y)\iff31|6(x+7y)$$  But $(6,31)=1\implies31|6(x+7y)\iff31|(x+7y)$

OR $$7(6x+11y)-11(x+7y)=31x$$

$$\implies7(6x+11y)\equiv11(x+7y)\pmod{31}$$

$$\implies31|7(6x+11y)\iff31|11(x+7y)$$  But $(31,11)=(31,7)=1$

Answer (score 0):

Hint

$31 \mid 31(x+2y) -5(6x+11y)$